# Parse android crashes not found the enable command

Tags: parse-platform, parse-error, parse-android-sdk

To enable parse crashes I need to write the command: ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);
But eclipse doesnt find the command. 
The error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Tk6T.png
what I need to do?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add the ParseCrashReporting-1.8.0.jar to dependencies.
You can download from: https://parse.com/downloads/android/Parse-Starter-Project/latest